# Connect GSM module via serial0 and GPS via USB

Tags: pi-3, serial, uart, gps, gsm

I have a GPS module connected vía UART in the GPIO. Now I want to add a GSM module to my proyect but my TX RX pins are busy with the GPS. I saw an adapter to connect the GPS through USB with a UART USB adapter and use the ttyUSB0 in the raspberry Pi 3 to receive the GPS data. 
Can I receive the GPS data with the ttyUSB0 and the GSM through the ttyS0 at the same time connecting the GPS module via USB and the GSM via GPIO ??

Thank you, and sorry for my english.

Comment: Could you accept my answer if it helps and answered your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use a USB (virtual) serial port and a TTL serial port to connect difficult type of modules. This is a common practice implemented on embedded system.

As on the software side, you have to program your software to read the GPS data or send/receive GSM data (SMS or mobile data) subject your requirement.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can connect more than one Serial devices to Raspberry pi 3.

There are USB-to-TTL converters which you need to plug in Raspberry Pi USB port. You can access that port by using `/dev/ttyUSB0`. This will act same as hardware serial port.

The Hardware Serial can still be connected to any other device and can be accessed with `/dev/ttyS0`.

You can buy USB-to-TTL converter from this [amazon - PL2303 Usb To Rs232 Ttl Converter Adapter for Aurdino Nano Raspberry PI](https://www.amazon.in/PL2303-Converter-Adapter-Aurdino-Raspberry/dp/B00UZERG94?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=_k_Cj0KCQiA14TjBRD_ARIsAOCmO9a0hY-30Bfi7emwLmGoQYUVx0xS6YpHv0ilR578YyyBx0fsXafzzmUaAvWOEALw_wcB_k_&gclid=Cj0KCQiA14TjBRD_ARIsAOCmO9a0hY-30Bfi7emwLmGoQYUVx0xS6YpHv0ilR578YyyBx0fsXafzzmUaAvWOEALw_wcB).